# Photoshop mask problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I create a masked image (blue) with a rounded rect, with the same rect as the background (red), the background shows through the corners of the masked image (see attached). How can I make it so no pixels show through?[image]

Comment: Does each shape have it's own mask or are they sharing one mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example image I think that I would do this with Clipping mask.

You could do something like:

1. Create a base layer of any color. this should have the rounded corners and or other shapes.
2. Create another two layers with blue and red rectangles in each one with the sides going past your base layer.
3. Then in the layers panel while pressing Alt key, point in between your base layer and one of the rectangle layers vertically ( the sides that are touching ). Then click right there between them and you should have a clipping mask. Repeat this step with any additional colors / elements you might want to add to it.

---

Tip: I sometimes make Shape layer and then put a texture layer ( that fills the whole document ) into clipping mask with the Shape layer, that way I can resize the shape layer if needed and the texture just sits there and wont get disturbed.

Comment: Brilliant, never knew this trick even existed..

Comment: @Plenilune you also might want to try putting Layer styles into your base layer, and experiment a bit. If you have cs6 it is also worth checking out the group clipping mask feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Clipping Mask, or a Group Mask, or even two paths, provided they were positioned with no overlap (the red area could be square finished, the blue area could have rounded corners on the bottom only).

Everything you need to know about vector masking in Photoshop can be found here:

http://bjango.com/articles/photoshopcs6masking/

I'd choose your approach based on what else you want to do with the shapes, and how you may edit them in the future.

Clipping Masks are brilliant though. Definitely one of Photoshop's best features.